# Chrome Bookmark with Multiple Keywords only Working if Current Page has a Link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, search-engine, bookmarks

There is this great code snippet for chrome's search engnie (chrome://settings/searchEngines) to make use of multiple search keywords:

```
javascript:var s='%s';url='https://my.url.com/navigation.do?key1=%s&key2=%s';query=''; urlchunks=url.split('%s');schunks=s.split(';');for(i=0; i<schunks.length; i++)query+=urlchunks[i]+schunks[i];location.replace(query);
```

I am experiencing that this is only working if there is a page loaded in the current tab.
It also works when current page is about:blank, but it does not work if I open a new tab (ctrl+t) and try to make use of the search engine. The engine simply does not trigger and open the url.
Also tried

```
window.location = ...
window.location.href = ...
location.replace(..)
window.open(..,'_self');
without success.
```

When I open a new tab (ctrl+t), I see a google search bar and the most recent websites as icons below.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.